# How to stack the tizk tables in block?

Tags: beamer, tikz-styles

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{adjustbox}     % adjusting table (too wide)
% Fancy tables
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,positioning} % tree
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}            % Table

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]{Findings 3} %{What's new?}

    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{$\{ [\phi(h),p(t+h)]_C \}$}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
            \matrix (m)%
            [matrix of math nodes,
            column 1/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
            column 2/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
            column 3/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
            column 4/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
            column 5/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
            column 6/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
            column 7/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
            column 8/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
            column 9/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
            nodes in empty cells
            ]{
                & K=3 & K=4 & K=5 & K=6 & K=7 & K=8 & K=9 & K=10 \\
                \hline
                C=2   & 4     & 7     & 8     & 9     & 10    & 11    & 12    & 13 \\
                C=3   & 4     & 10    & 11    & 12    & 13    & 14    & 15    & 16 \\
                C=4   & 4     & 10    & 14    & 15    & 16    & 17    & 18    & 19 \\
                C=5   & 4     & 10    & 16    & 18    & 19    & 20    & 21    & 22 \\
                C=6   & 4     & 10    & 16    & 21    & 22    & 23    & 24    & 25 \\
                C=7   & 4     & 10    & 16    & 23    & 25    & 26    & 27    & 28 \\
                C=8   & 4     & 10    & 16    & 23    & 28    & 29    & 30    & 31 \\
                C=9   & 4     & 10    & 16    & 23    & 31    & 32    & 33    & 34 \\
                C=10  & 4     & 10    & 16    & 23    & 31    & 35    & 36    & 37 \\
            };
            \draw ([yshift=0.5em]m-1-1.north east) -- (m-10-1.south east);
        \only<2->{
            \draw[red,thick]
            (m-2-2.north east) --
            (m-3-2.south east) --
            (m-3-3.south east) --
            (m-4-3.south east) --
            (m-4-4.south east) --
            (m-6-4.south east) --
            (m-6-5.south east) --
            (m-6-5.south east) --
            (m-9-5.south east) --
            (m-9-6.south east) --
            (m-10-6.south east)
            ;
            \draw[blue,dashed,thick]
            (m-2-2.north east) --
            (m-2-2.south east) --
            (m-2-4.south east) --
            (m-3-4.south east) --
            (m-3-6.south east) --
            (m-4-6.south east) --
            (m-4-8.south east) --
            (m-5-8.south east) --
            (m-5-9.south east);
        }
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{block}
% \\
        \begin{block}{$\{ [\phi(t+h),p(h)]_C \}$}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
            \matrix (m)%
            [matrix of math nodes,
            column 1/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
            column 2/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
            column 3/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
            column 4/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
            column 5/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
            column 6/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
            column 7/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
            column 8/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
            column 9/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
            nodes in empty cells
            ]{
                & K=3 & K=4 & K=5 & K=6 & K=7 & K=8 & K=9 & K=10 \\
                \hline
                C=2   & 4     & 7     & 8     & 9     & 10    & 11    & 12    & 13 \\
                C=3   & 4     & 10    & 11    & 12    & 13    & 14    & 15    & 16 \\
                C=4   & 4     & 10    & 14    & 15    & 16    & 17    & 18    & 19 \\
                C=5   & 4     & 10    & 16    & 18    & 19    & 20    & 21    & 22 \\
                C=6   & 4     & 10    & 16    & 21    & 22    & 23    & 24    & 25 \\
                C=7   & 4     & 10    & 16    & 23    & 25    & 26    & 27    & 28 \\
                C=8   & 4     & 10    & 16    & 23    & 28    & 29    & 30    & 31 \\
                C=9   & 4     & 10    & 16    & 23    & 31    & 32    & 33    & 34 \\
                C=10  & 4     & 10    & 16    & 23    & 31    & 35    & 36    & 37 \\
            };
            \draw ([yshift=0.5em]m-1-1.north east) -- (m-10-1.south east);
        \only<2->{
            \draw[red,thick]
            (m-2-2.north east) --
            (m-3-2.south east) --
            (m-3-3.south east) --
            (m-4-3.south east) --
            (m-4-4.south east) --
            (m-6-4.south east) --
            (m-6-5.south east) --
            (m-6-5.south east) --
            (m-9-5.south east) --
            (m-9-6.south east) --
            (m-10-6.south east)
            ;
            \draw[blue,dashed,thick]
            (m-2-2.north east) --
            (m-2-2.south east) --
            (m-2-4.south east) --
            (m-3-4.south east) --
            (m-3-6.south east) --
            (m-4-6.south east) --
            (m-4-8.south east) --
            (m-5-8.south east) --
            (m-5-9.south east);
        }
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{block}
    \end{adjustbox}
%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What I want to get is:

One table on top of the other in `Block`s.
The lines in the tables come out from `\only<2->`

I can't seem to make `adjustbox`, `\only<>`, `block` and `\\` to work well together.

I can only get them side by side like this:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use one table? You can fake them being two by putting an empty row. Or maybe I'm missing the issue.

Comment: I want to use the `block` environment for each tables so that they look nicer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same to apply it to one table?

Comment: @Alenanno I would prefer to do them separately. By the way, the example code I have given is not exactly the content. The tables have different  cell values and each tables represent a different model. That's why I want to use `block`, so that I can put the model names as the titles for the blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `adjustbox` approach is problematic, as this will scale the tables to occupy the whole textwidth, but then there is not enough room to stack two of the on top of each other.

**Possibility 1:** Why not simply scale the tikz picture with `scale=0.5, every node/.style={scale=0.5}`?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,positioning} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}            

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]{Findings 3} 
\begin{block}{$\{ [\phi(h),p(t+h)]_C \}$}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, every node/.style={scale=0.5}]
    \matrix (m)[%
          matrix of math nodes,
        column 1/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 2/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 3/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 4/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 5/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 6/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 7/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 8/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 9/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        nodes in empty cells
    ]{
      & K=3 & K=4 & K=5 & K=6 & K=7 & K=8 & K=9 & K=10 \\
      \hline
      C=2   & 4   & 7   & 8   & 9     & 10    & 11    & 12    & 13 \\
      C=3   & 4   & 10  & 11  & 12    & 13    & 14    & 15    & 16 \\
      C=4   & 4   & 10  & 14  & 15    & 16    & 17    & 18    & 19 \\
      C=5   & 4   & 10  & 16  & 18    & 19    & 20    & 21    & 22 \\
      C=6   & 4   & 10  & 16  & 21    & 22    & 23    & 24    & 25 \\
      C=7   & 4   & 10  & 16  & 23    & 25    & 26    & 27    & 28 \\
      C=8   & 4   & 10  & 16  & 23    & 28    & 29    & 30    & 31 \\
      C=9   & 4   & 10  & 16  & 23    & 31    & 32    & 33    & 34 \\
      C=10  & 4   & 10  & 16  & 23    & 31    & 35    & 36    & 37 \\
    };
    \draw ([yshift=0.5em]m-1-1.north east) -- (m-10-1.south east);
        \only<2->{
            \draw[red,thick]
            (m-2-2.north east) --
            (m-3-2.south east) --
            (m-3-3.south east) --
            (m-4-3.south east) --
            (m-4-4.south east) --
            (m-6-4.south east) --
            (m-6-5.south east) --
            (m-6-5.south east) --
            (m-9-5.south east) --
            (m-9-6.south east) --
            (m-10-6.south east)
            ;
            \draw[blue,dashed,thick]
            (m-2-2.north east) --
            (m-2-2.south east) --
            (m-2-4.south east) --
            (m-3-4.south east) --
            (m-3-6.south east) --
            (m-4-6.south east) --
            (m-4-8.south east) --
            (m-5-8.south east) --
            (m-5-9.south east);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{block}

\begin{block}{$\{ [\phi(h),p(t+h)]_C \}$}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, every node/.style={scale=0.5}]
    \matrix (m)[%
          matrix of math nodes,
        column 1/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 2/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 3/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 4/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 5/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 6/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 7/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 8/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 9/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        nodes in empty cells
    ]{
      & K=3 & K=4 & K=5 & K=6 & K=7 & K=8 & K=9 & K=10 \\
      \hline
      C=2   & 4   & 7   & 8   & 9     & 10    & 11    & 12    & 13 \\
      C=3   & 4   & 10  & 11  & 12    & 13    & 14    & 15    & 16 \\
      C=4   & 4   & 10  & 14  & 15    & 16    & 17    & 18    & 19 \\
      C=5   & 4   & 10  & 16  & 18    & 19    & 20    & 21    & 22 \\
      C=6   & 4   & 10  & 16  & 21    & 22    & 23    & 24    & 25 \\
      C=7   & 4   & 10  & 16  & 23    & 25    & 26    & 27    & 28 \\
      C=8   & 4   & 10  & 16  & 23    & 28    & 29    & 30    & 31 \\
      C=9   & 4   & 10  & 16  & 23    & 31    & 32    & 33    & 34 \\
      C=10  & 4   & 10  & 16  & 23    & 31    & 35    & 36    & 37 \\
    };
    \draw ([yshift=0.5em]m-1-1.north east) -- (m-10-1.south east);
        \only<2->{
            \draw[red,thick]
            (m-2-2.north east) --
            (m-3-2.south east) --
            (m-3-3.south east) --
            (m-4-3.south east) --
            (m-4-4.south east) --
            (m-6-4.south east) --
            (m-6-5.south east) --
            (m-6-5.south east) --
            (m-9-5.south east) --
            (m-9-6.south east) --
            (m-10-6.south east)
            ;
            \draw[blue,dashed,thick]
            (m-2-2.north east) --
            (m-2-2.south east) --
            (m-2-4.south east) --
            (m-3-4.south east) --
            (m-3-6.south east) --
            (m-4-6.south east) --
            (m-4-8.south east) --
            (m-5-8.south east) --
            (m-5-9.south east);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Possibility 2:** Let beamer do the work

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,positioning} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}            

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile, shrink]{Findings 3} 
\begin{block}{$\{ [\phi(h),p(t+h)]_C \}$}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m)[%
          matrix of math nodes,
        column 1/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 2/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 3/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 4/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 5/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 6/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 7/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 8/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 9/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        nodes in empty cells
    ]{
      & K=3 & K=4 & K=5 & K=6 & K=7 & K=8 & K=9 & K=10 \\
      \hline
      C=2   & 4   & 7   & 8   & 9     & 10    & 11    & 12    & 13 \\
      C=3   & 4   & 10  & 11  & 12    & 13    & 14    & 15    & 16 \\
      C=4   & 4   & 10  & 14  & 15    & 16    & 17    & 18    & 19 \\
      C=5   & 4   & 10  & 16  & 18    & 19    & 20    & 21    & 22 \\
      C=6   & 4   & 10  & 16  & 21    & 22    & 23    & 24    & 25 \\
      C=7   & 4   & 10  & 16  & 23    & 25    & 26    & 27    & 28 \\
      C=8   & 4   & 10  & 16  & 23    & 28    & 29    & 30    & 31 \\
      C=9   & 4   & 10  & 16  & 23    & 31    & 32    & 33    & 34 \\
      C=10  & 4   & 10  & 16  & 23    & 31    & 35    & 36    & 37 \\
    };
    \draw ([yshift=0.5em]m-1-1.north east) -- (m-10-1.south east);
        \only<2->{
            \draw[red,thick]
            (m-2-2.north east) --
            (m-3-2.south east) --
            (m-3-3.south east) --
            (m-4-3.south east) --
            (m-4-4.south east) --
            (m-6-4.south east) --
            (m-6-5.south east) --
            (m-6-5.south east) --
            (m-9-5.south east) --
            (m-9-6.south east) --
            (m-10-6.south east)
            ;
            \draw[blue,dashed,thick]
            (m-2-2.north east) --
            (m-2-2.south east) --
            (m-2-4.south east) --
            (m-3-4.south east) --
            (m-3-6.south east) --
            (m-4-6.south east) --
            (m-4-8.south east) --
            (m-5-8.south east) --
            (m-5-9.south east);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{block}

\begin{block}{$\{ [\phi(h),p(t+h)]_C \}$}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m)[%
          matrix of math nodes,
        column 1/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 2/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 3/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 4/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 5/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 6/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 7/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 8/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        column 9/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=4em}},
        nodes in empty cells
    ]{
      & K=3 & K=4 & K=5 & K=6 & K=7 & K=8 & K=9 & K=10 \\
      \hline
      C=2   & 4   & 7   & 8   & 9     & 10    & 11    & 12    & 13 \\
      C=3   & 4   & 10  & 11  & 12    & 13    & 14    & 15    & 16 \\
      C=4   & 4   & 10  & 14  & 15    & 16    & 17    & 18    & 19 \\
      C=5   & 4   & 10  & 16  & 18    & 19    & 20    & 21    & 22 \\
      C=6   & 4   & 10  & 16  & 21    & 22    & 23    & 24    & 25 \\
      C=7   & 4   & 10  & 16  & 23    & 25    & 26    & 27    & 28 \\
      C=8   & 4   & 10  & 16  & 23    & 28    & 29    & 30    & 31 \\
      C=9   & 4   & 10  & 16  & 23    & 31    & 32    & 33    & 34 \\
      C=10  & 4   & 10  & 16  & 23    & 31    & 35    & 36    & 37 \\
    };
    \draw ([yshift=0.5em]m-1-1.north east) -- (m-10-1.south east);
        \only<2->{
            \draw[red,thick]
            (m-2-2.north east) --
            (m-3-2.south east) --
            (m-3-3.south east) --
            (m-4-3.south east) --
            (m-4-4.south east) --
            (m-6-4.south east) --
            (m-6-5.south east) --
            (m-6-5.south east) --
            (m-9-5.south east) --
            (m-9-6.south east) --
            (m-10-6.south east)
            ;
            \draw[blue,dashed,thick]
            (m-2-2.north east) --
            (m-2-2.south east) --
            (m-2-4.south east) --
            (m-3-4.south east) --
            (m-3-6.south east) --
            (m-4-6.south east) --
            (m-4-8.south east) --
            (m-5-8.south east) --
            (m-5-9.south east);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]